# What syntactic function does 'us' have here?

Tags: parts-of-speech

> We (subject) need (verb) you (object) to meet (infinitive) us (**object?**) at the library (prepositional phrase) at 7 (prepositional phrase) tonight (adverb).

What type of object is "us"?

Comment: Object of the infinitive "to meet."

Comment: It might help to distinguish between the lexical classification of words as parts of speech (nouns, verbs, adjectives, etc.) and the syntactic labels they have as roles in sentences (subjects, objects, predicates, modifiers, etc.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The word *us* is the Direct Object of the verb *meet* in the Original Poster's sentence.

The syntactic functions (grammatical relations) in the sentence are:

Sentence level:

- **Subject**, *We*;
- **Predicate**, *need you  to meet us at the library at 7 tonight*

Within the Predicate:

- **Predicator** (Head of the verb phrase), *need*
- **Direct Object**, *you*
- **Catenative Complement**, *to meet us at the library at 7 tonight*

Within the Catenative Complement:

- **Marker of subordination**, to
- **Predicator** (Head of the verb phrase), *meet*
- **Direct Object**, *us*
- **(locative) Adjunct**, *at the library*
- **(temporal) Adjunct**, *at 7*
- **(temporal) Adjunct**, *tonight*

Comment: @SunnyHills You're welcome. My pleasure :)

Comment: That was a good answer; however, the true object of 'need' is 'meet' rather than 'you'.  If it was just 'you', the brain would be unable to link 'need' to 'meet'.  By linking to 'meet', 'you' is still obtainable (as the subject of 'meet').  Grammatical analysis will need to be true to neurology, when we can map the latter.

Comment: @AmI I don't see why that should be a problem necessarily. The more detailed analysis of the sentence is that it *us* is a *raised* Object. This means that the syntactic object is interpreted as an argument of the subordinate clause. In transformational grammar this means that in the underlying structure *us* was the Subject of *meet*, but that it is raised into a higher clause in the surface structure.

Comment: Yes, 'us' is a sub-subject that has been raised to the object case, but that doesn't necessarily mean that it is the object of 'need'.  I want you to see that the brain can't just store: 'We need you', and 'you meet us'.  It must store something like: 'We need {a meeting, between you and us}'; We need ->meet,  and You might meet ->us.